# Code help about creating custom loss function in tensor flow

Tags: python, loss-functions, tensorflow

I am trying to create my custom loss function for solving the regression problem using the RNN layers.

For my specific dataset, I need the following conditions for updating my loss function:

```
def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred):
     if y_true>b or y_true<a:
          return sum((y_true-y_pred).^2*2)
     else:
          return sum((y_true-y_pred).^2)
```

Basically, this loss function is penalizing more on predicting incorrect extreme values. I wonder if I am going to write using `tf.cond()`, how should I deal with the multiple conditions? Also my a, b are single values, so I need to convert those to an array in order to compare with y_true?

Any answers or thoughts are appreciated.

Comment: Hi Emily. In case you are not time-constrained, have you considered using [PyTorch](https://pytorch.org/) instead of TensorFlow? PyTorch has been known to be more "Pythonic" than TensorFlow, since you can use if statements as you would in normal Python. I have personally used both TensorFlow and PyTorch and prefer the latter for its user friendliness. [Here](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/basics/intro.html) is a quick tutorial. Sorry I couldn't be of more help.

Comment: Also, I would suggest you instead ask your question on Stack Overflow with the [tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tensorflow) tag.

Comment: Thank you! I will take a look at this!

Comment: If you do use PyTorch, be sure to ask your questions in the dedicated [PyTorch forum](https://discuss.pytorch.org/).